# How to fetch data before component render with React-Hooks and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm a junior FED and very new in React-Hooks and Redux. I'm working in an app with React Hooks and Redux and a I need the data before the rendering of a component.

I manage the state in Redux, cause I need in diff components, the thing is with Redux Hooks I dont have something like `componentWillMount` for dispaching an action. So I manage to work making the dispatch inside `useEffect()` controlled with an if-statement, but for me is not a good aproach since is asking every 1 sec is the data or no.

I also put the dispatch in the button that take me to that view, and that work fine, the thing is that if yo handwritte the url in the browser the data isn't load. I'm currenty trying to understand the suspense and lazy components, but I'm not shure if I'm going in the correct path. If someone can give me a hint o recommend something to read I would really appreciate it. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Do you actually need the data *before* rendering the component or do you just need the data eventually? Dispatching an action *once* when the component mounts is possible with useEffect and an empty array as second argument. It's hard to give you advice without seeing any code.

Comment: Hi! I appreciate your answer. I understand that it's hard without the code, what happens is that it is an internal project and I cannot share it, besides what I am looking for is to understand the logic and good practices beyond whether the code works.

Comment: It is a screen with components that show data that I bring from an api. I managed to bring them after rendering it within the useEffect, but I don't know how that affects the performance, since I don't have a cut-off parameter more than an if-statement, that's why I think that if I manage to have the data before rendering it would be a better practice, but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Comment: I think the best practice is to fetch once the component mounts ie. to do it in a useEffect with an empty dependency array. In your JSX you can conditionally load your data. You can use suspense for loading components but for data fetching it's still experimental I think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will continue working on that :)

Comment: Yes! It worked very well, I didn't really understand the empty dependency array that you where telling me until I read this post: https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-custom-usefetch-react-hook

So, again, thanks to both of you